# My daughter sits/ is sitting/ will sit for hours watchingTV

Tags: meaning-in-context, semantics, present-tense, future, present-progressive

> **My daughter  is sitting  for  hours  watching TV**
>
> **My  daughter  sits  for  hours  watching  TV.**
>
> **My  daughter  will sit  for hours  watching  TV.**

From the  context  it  seems that  the  father  is  complaining  against  his  daughter's  watching TV too much.But  I  am not  sure  when to  use them.

I  would  like to  know  the  difference  among  the  three sentences. or  the  shades of difference  in meaning.

I  can  not find  the difference  by  referring  to  grammar  books or searching  on Google.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like a habitual action. In that case, "My daughter sits for hours watching TV" is correct.

The first one should be modified, "My daughter is watching TV," sounds like a reply to the question "What is your daughter doing?"

The third one also refers to a habit, like, "You don't know; she is a TV addict; She (my daughter) will sit for hours watching TV."

These are the general uses, and there should be other situations too.

Answer (score 0):

My daughter sits for hours watching TV, is the right answer.
Since the dad is complaining, this is the best and right answer. We don't use My daughter is sitting for hours watching TV for a report.
But we can use the third one too. But my opinion is the first one since he is complaining of her old action which she hasn't resigned from it. It is a habitual act.

```
Thanks!
```